# what is different between DirectX API(and OpenGL API call) and normal system call on windows?

Tags: opengl, operating-system, directx

I have question about the method how windows os changes mode from user mode(app code) to kernel mode(like driver code)  when Application use directX(or OpenGL) function or normal function(system call like printf).

what is different?

If there is different for performance, I want to know about this.

Comment: What do you understand by "normal system call"? Eventually everything that talks to the kernel has to go through some system call. DirectX and OpenGL are no exceptions.

Comment: This question is far too broad for StackOverflow.  Please consult applicable web sites or textbooks for the basic information.  When you have a specific question, we can help.

Comment: @datenwolf Thank you for your answer. Your answer made me understand it.

Comment: @Prune Thank your for answer. I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually anything that outputs to a device will involve a user-mode/kernel-mode transition. When you do `printf` it happens when the C library calls `WriteConsole` although likely after some amount of buffering happens to minimize the number of transitions. Essentially the same thing happens with DirectX and OpenGL: do as much as you can in user-mode, do what you need in kernel-mode in a driver.

The specifics vary widely based on which version of the OS, which driver model (XPDM or WDDM) you are talking about, and which version of Direct3D or OpenGL you are asking about in particular.

From an application developer perspective, what you need to know is: try to avoid calling `Draw` a zillion times with just a few triangles in each if you want a good frame-rate.

For Direct3D 10 and 11, the best generic performance advice is found in [Windows to Reality: Getting the Most out of Direct3D 10 Graphics in Your Games (Gamefest 2007)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/0/4/a04deeb2-d7e2-42a5-984a-9ea5c92bfeb2/Windows%20to%20Reality%20-%20Getting%20the%20Most%20out%20of%20Direct3D%2010%20Graphics%20in%20your%20Games.zip)

For legacy Direct3D 9, see [Accurately Profiling Direct3D API Calls (Direct3D 9)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172234.aspx)